# Adding controls like pause and play to media player

Tags: android, media-player, media

I have been able to play audio from my firebase storage and i want the song to stop and start when a user clicks on same button but i haven't been able to get get the right code for that.

this is what i have tried

```
 MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
                mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                        if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                            mediaPlayer.start();
                        }else {
                            mediaPlayer.stop();
                        }
                    }
                });
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

The above code is correct, now do one thing create button listener and write below code

```
button.setOnClickListener(view.onCLickListeners(){

 @override
 public void onClick(){
   if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
           mediaPlayer.play();
    }
  else {
          mediaPlayer.pause();
       }
}});
```

And please define mediaplayer globally.

Comment: after it stops it doesn't start again on another click